# Uncaught TypeError: children[i].children is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that gets the all the li elements with the name "children-li" from a list "my_dynamic_list".
each li element has three checkboxes of the names object_ck_bx, write_ck_bx, view_ck_bx, I need to get the values of that checksboxes, but I get "children is not a function", why the code can access to li tag name but can not access li children?

```
 function getTreeData() {
        // Get All Li elements thats contains the checkboxes form the type object,read,write
        var children = $('#my_dynamic_list').children().find('li[name=children-li]');
        var extracted_data = [];
        for (i = 0; i < children.length ; i++) {
            alert(children[i].tagName); //this gives li

            if (children[i].children().find('input[name=object_ck_bx]').checked == true) { // This Line gives Uncaught TypeError: children[i].children is not a function
                var profile_code = children[i].children().find('input[name=object_ck_bx]').id;
                var view = children[i].children().find('input[name=view_ck_bx]').checked;
                var write = children[i].children().find('input[name=write_ck_bx]').checked;
                alert('profile_code' + profile_code);
                var item = [];
                item = { Id: profile_code, read: view, write: write };
                extracted_data.push(item);
            }

        }
      //  alert(extracted_data);
        return extracted_data;
    }
```

The Html Code:
[image]

The li properties in the browser looks like
[image: The li properties in the browser looks like]

Comment: There has to be a dupetarget for this. When you index into a jQuery object, you get a raw DOM element, not a jQuery object. DOM elements don't have a `children` function (they do have a `children` property).(Edit: It was easier to find than I thought, I got lucky with my search term.) So `children[i].children().find(...)` would be `children.eq(i).children().find(...)` .

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried that first before posting but it did not work, thank you for your effort.

Comment: All due respect, then you did it wrong, since `$(children[i])` is just a long-winded, non-idiomatic way to write `children.eq(i)`.

Comment: it's correct , I fix that by using jquery constructor and eq().
thanks

Comment: No need for the constructor **and** `eq`. `children` is **already** a jQuery object, and `eq` returns a jQuery object. Again: `children.eq(i).children().find(...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `.children()` for the first time, you get back a plain array of `HTMLElement` objects. The method `.children()` you are trying to call is a method of a jQuery collection. So in order to make a jQuery object from the plain `HTMLElement` you get returned from getting `children[i]`, wrap that into the jQuery constructor, like so:

```
$(children[i]).children() // ...
```