# Uncaught typeError children() is not a function when using class filter

Tags: jquery, class, innerhtml, children

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<ul>
   <li id="a">
      <a class="x">
         <span class="hidden"></span>
      </a>
      <span class="showing">Some text</span>
   </li>
   <li id="b">
      <a class="x">
         <span class="hidden"></span>
      </a>
      <span class="showing">Some text</span>
   </li>
   <li id="c">
      <a class="x">
         <span class="hidden"></span>
      </a>
      <span class="showing">Some text</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want to change the text of the last SPAN element in the third LI element, so I have created the following jQuery script:

```
document.getElementById("c").children(".showing").innerHTML = "Peer Reviewed";
```

The script returns an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).children is not a function"

What am I doing wrong?

I checked [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397834/uncaught-typeerror-childreni-children-is-not-a-function), but those were all very different cases.

The list isn't static, but is built on user choices, so I have to use the ID of the last LI element (which is static).

There will always be only ONE response answering this function (i.e. there is always only one SPAN with this class under this ID).

I believed the issue was that what I am getting is an array, even if it has just one element in it, and I need to somehow select that specific element.

I tried the following script, but got the same error message:

```
var limiterchange = document.getElementById("appcustomlimiter0removeli").children(".limiter");
    $limiterchange[0].innerHTML = "Peer Reviewed";
```

Comment: `HTMLElement.children` isn't a function, it is a property.

Comment: @Phiter according to the documentation, it should return all direct children of the selected element: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_children.asp

Comment: Yeah but `getElementById` doesn't return a jQuery element. It returns an HTML element. In order to be able to use jQuery's `.children`, you'll have to use a jQuery element. Like this: `$("#appcustomlimiter0removeli").children()`

Comment: Thanks @Phiter. I accepted the answer below, but I now understand what you were saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the thing for you.

```
var el = document.getElementById("c");
el.getElementsByClassName('showing')[0].innerHTML = "Peer Reviewed"
```

or aleternatively you can use:

```
var el = document.getElementById("c");
el.querySelector('span.showing').innerHTML = "Peer Reviewed"
```

Comment: The first option returned an error: Uncaught TypeError: limiterchange.getElementsbyClassName is not a function. The second one worked like a charm! Thank you so much!